# Configuration steps for Postgres db

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I want to build and run following application https://github.com/sdeleuze/geospatial-messenger

I have little experience with backend and data bases so I need some guidance with following installation step:

> Customize database configuration on application.yml.

**application.yml**

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.web.servlet: INFO
spring:
  datasource:
    platform: "postgis"
    driver-class-name: "org.postgis.DriverWrapper"
    url: "jdbc:postgresql_postGIS://localhost/geospatial-messenger"
    username: "postgres"
  mvc:
      async:
        request-timeout: 1000000
```

Please outline steps that I should perform with my data base to configure it according to a file.

I have PostgreSQL 10 on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the PostgreSQL installed, so you only need PostGIS for this to work. For Ubuntu, it is better if you use UbuntuGIS. You can add UbuntuGIS repository and install PostGIS from it. http://trac.osgeo.org/ubuntugis/wiki/QuickStartGuide.

Another way is to use PostgreSQL's repository http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS24UbuntuPGSQL10Apt

Comment: A have already installed UbuntuGIS, Should i do anything to customise database? Or I should just spin up a DB server and run Gradle task?

Comment: I mean how server will know that it should respond by url: jdbc:postgresql_postGIS://localhost/geospatial-messenger

Comment: That is just jdbc driver, Gradle should do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
After installation of PostgreSQL10, please follow the below steps :
1.  Login to root user, run this command su – postgres
2.  Locate the pg_hba.conf file by running select Query: select current_setting('hba_file');
3.  Modify the pg_hba.conf file
4.  Example : vim /prod/pgsql_10/pg_hba.conf command.
5.  Press insert key where you want to modify and save it using esc + :wq
Example: host   all    all   10.10.11.183/32   md5 
trust – without password authentication
md5 – with password authentication
6.  After modification, we should restart the postgres service using this command
systemctl restart postgresql-10.service
7.  Also modify the postgresql.conf file as same as pg_hba.conf file.
locate postgresql.conf
vim /prod/pgsql_10/postgresql.conf
8.  After modification, we should restart the postgres service using this command
systemctl restart postgresql-10.service
9.  To login postgres, run this command psql -U esb(user) postgres(DB)
```

Comment: Thank you! But everything worked automatically somehow as @Tejas Sarade said. Any way this could be useful to someone.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.